# Not able to see MediaStream properties value in console

Tags: node.js, server, webrtc, mediastream

I am totally new to WebRTC and Node.js  I was trying to build sample webRTC app using the tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_media_stream_apis.htm
 I have followed exactly the same steps except that I have created my own Nodejs server using nodejs tutorial from same site. As mentioned in webrtc tutorial I am not able to see properties value of MediaStream in console . In my case its totally blank. Is anything I am doing wrong. My file is running on http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html and I am able to see my local video .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to see this. Try this:

1. In your browser, open a new empty tab, right-click and pick *Inspect Element*.
2. Go to the *Console* tab, paste in the following, and hit Enter: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(stream => console.log(stream)).catch(e => console.error(e))`
3. Select to share your camera.

You should see something like this (varies a bit by browser still):

```
MediaStream {id: "JFK9GaWaTxPptJVuKjNlj9lmfvNarWaXANjv", active: true, onactive: null, oninactive: null, onended: null…}
```

> **Note:** Always be cautious about people on the internet telling you to paste things into console. :)

Comment: @jim VM218:1 Uncaught TypeError: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is not a function this error comes in new tab

Comment: @DishaJain what browser and version?